# How to posititon text in a slick slider and ensure it does not move around

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm currently trying to overlay text over the image in my slick slider, however even though I have overlaid the text when I resize the window the text seems to move around in the image. How do I fix this? Is there a different way to overlay text over an image in an image carousel? please do advise, my code pen is also linked below

This is my codepen
https://codepen.io/rahil8533/pen/OJzpzxo
HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css">
  </head>
<body>

  <section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.cc/7ayxq3q5l/cg5.jpg">
     <div class="content">
        <h2>Covid 19 measures on campus</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.cc/zccz3svft/cg6.jpg">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>2Covid 19 measures on campus</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://s26.postimg.cc/7g2ozrxgp/cg4.jpg">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>3Covid 19 measures on campus</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
        arrows: false
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

````
 html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0px 0px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
    }
    
.slick-dots li button:before {
    font-size: 10px; !important
}

    .slick-prev,
    .slick-next {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
.content{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the height of your `h2` textbox follows the height of the window. Add the setting `adaptiveHeight: false` to your slick code as well as the following css and js  updates.

You must update your `h2` and `.content` with the following css styles:

```css
  .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    z-index: 99;
  }

  h2 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Update your JavaScript to the following:

```js
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready', function() {
          $(".regular").slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            arrows: false,
            adaptiveHeight: false
          }).on("setPosition", function (event, slick) {
             $(".content > h2").css("height", slick.$slides.height() + "px");
          });
        });
      </script>
```

The codepen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/abatista6/pen/rNpmLPR).

Answer (score 0):

Change the content in the CSS to :

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -190px;
    left: 5;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-bottom:-65px
}
```

The relative position will change position on resize accordingly. The margin-bottom makes sure the dots are also in place.